# Create 1-to-1 relationship in Vapor Fluent asynchronously

Tags: swift, asynchronous, fluent, vapor

`Vapor` `Fluent` question.
I have the following code to save a `User` to a `Postgres`.

```
User
@Parent(key: FieldKeys.profile) var profile: Profile
```

...

```
let profile = User.Profile()
try await profile.save(on: request.db)
                            
if let profileID = try await User.Profile.query(on: request.db).all().last?.id {
    user.$profile.id = profileID; print("Profile created with ID=\(profileID)")
}
try await user.save(on: request.db)
```

My concern here is that another request could come in at the same time and create an entry in the Profile table and its `id` will have been returned as the last instead of the previous entry's `id`.

Is there a guaranteed way to create a user-profile relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a model in Fluent the ID is populated for you from the returned data in the query. So you can write

```swift
let profile = User.Profile()
try await profile.save(on: request.db)

let profileID = try profile.requireID()         
user.$profile.id = profileID
try await user.save(on: request.db)
```

You could also use one of the `attach` helpers from Fluent

Answer (score 2):

Vapor has the ability to create transactions so you can be certain nothing will intervene. Try something like:

```swift
try await request.db.transaction { database in
    let user = try await User.query...
    let profile = Profile()
    try await profile.save(on: database)
    user.$profile.id = profile.id
    try await user.save(on: database)
}
```